# Consume SOAP based web serices using Kony

Tags: soap, temenos-quantum

I have a wsdl file,please help me how I consume SOAP based web service using coding through Kony Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Kony fully supports consuming a SOAP service.  Using the Kony Studio, you will be creating a SOAP service call, and then calling that service call in your Javascript in your application.

You can see the instructions on how to create the SOAP service [here](http://docs.kony.com/KonyLibrary/#../Subsystems/Kony_MBaaS_User_Guide/Content/creating_a_web_service.htm?Highlight=wsdl)

http://docs.kony.com/KonyLibrary/#../Subsystems/Kony_MBaaS_User_Guide/Content/creating_a_web_service.htm?Highlight=wsdl

Next, you will want to use the Event Editor or Kony API's to call your service.  Once your service is defined, you can call it as you would any other service.

Comment: I have follow this tutorials, but I am not getting response. I need to send two parameter userId and password then expected output is as-           <result>
            <response>
               <responseCode>0</responseCode>
               <responseMessage>User sim is valid.</responseMessage>
            </response>
         </result>
      
but i am not getting response. Please help me for the same that how I send request for the same.

Comment: So when you are setting up the service in the Service Editor, and press the "Get Response" button, are you seeing your results appear in the bottom "Response" tab?

Comment: Yes, in that place I got accurate response but when I call through coding or javascript file then I am not getting the response.

Comment: OK, that's a great sign; means that the fundamental plumbing is working.  Couple of more "did you plug it in?" questions:
Did you publish your service to your Kony server?  Are you specifying the right server address in your app?  Are you checking your return codes from the service?  Try using the Event Editor to build up the connection to the server ( even if in a test button to check it working ) to verify that you are getting a good connection, and debug to check what status codes you are getting back from the server for the service call.  Check the documentation for the return values.

Comment: When I right click the project and click o Publish Services tab then a window is open then I click on Publish services, the Connection refused error found in console. Please help me out of this.

Comment: Opening connection to http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/direct and after that Connection refused error shown in console

Comment: OK, so sounds like the issue is not with SOAP or with your code but with the server.  The URL for the server is going to be your IP address ( sometimes the 127.0.0.1 is not routed properly ) so use ipconfig to get your IP, and set that to your Kony Server in your project properties and try publishing again.  Also, if you haven't already done so, go ahead and research this on the Kony Forum and put your question there as well ( actively monitored by Kony support. )  But try using the ip of your machine and let us know the results.

Answer (score 0):

Kony Studio is now deprecated you should use instead Kony Visualizer 7.* or 8.* along with Kony Mobile Fabric 7.* or 8.*.